# Mixing mathematical expression with control flow

Tags: algorithm, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to know, how expressions are parsed when are mixed with control flow.

Let's assume such syntax:

```
case 
  when a == Method() + 1 
    then Something(1) 
  when a == Other() - 2
    then 1
  else 0
end
```

We've got here two conditional expressions, `Method() + 1`, `Something(1)` and `0`. Each can be translated to postfix by `Shunting-yard algorithm` and then easily translated into `AST`. But is it possible to extend this algorithm to handle control - flow also? Or are there other approaches to solve such mixing of expressions and control flows?

another example:

```
a == b ? 1 : 2
```

also how can I classify such expression: `a between b and c`, can I say that `between` is three arguments function? Or is there any special name for such expressions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "control flow" here? `... between ... and ...` doesn't really sound like what I think of as a control flow construct. Do you just mean "ternary operator"?

Comment: Your're right, I should not use control flow sentence. I'm not sure how to classify such expression. It's not ternary operator, I think, how would you name it?

Comment: `a between b and c` has three arguments, and it is an expression yielding a Boolean. It is a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly parse the ternary operator with an operator-precedence grammar. In

```
expr ? expr : expr
```

the binary "operator" here is `? expr :`, which conveniently starts and ends with an operator token (albeit different ones). To adapt shunting yard to that, assign the right-precedence of <kbd>?</kbd> and the left-precedence of <kbd>:</kbd> to the precedence of the `?:` operator. The left-precedence of <kbd>?</kbd> and the right-precedence of <kbd>:</kbd> are ±∞, just like parentheses (which, in effect, they are).

Since the `case` statement is basically repeated application of the ternary operator, using slightly different spellings for the tokens, and yields to a similar solution. (Here `case when` and `end` are purely parenthetic, while `then` and the remaining `when`s correspond to `?` and `:`.)

Having said that, it really is simpler to use an LALR(1) parser generator, and there is almost certainly one available for whatever language you are writing in.

---

It's clear that both the ternary operator and OP's case statement are operator grammars:

1. Ternary operator:

   ```
   ternary-expr: non-ternary-expr
               | non-ternary-expr '?' expr ':' ternary-expr
   ```

   Normally, the ternary operator will be lower precedence from any other operator and associate to the right, which is how the above is written. In C and other languages ternary expressions have the same precedence as assignment expressions, which is straightforward to add. That results in the relationships

   - `X ·> ?`
   - `? <· X`
   - `? ·=· :`
   - `X ·> :`
   - `: <· X`
2. Case statement (one of many possible formulations):

   ```
   case_statement: 'case' case_body 'else' expr 'end'
   case_body: 'when' expr 'then' expr
            | case_body 'when' expr 'then' expr
   ```

   Here are the precedence relationships for the above grammar:

   - `case <· when`
   - `case ·=· else`
   - `when <· X` (see below)
   - `when ·=· then`
   - `then ·> when`
   - `then ·> else`
   - `else <· X`
   - `else ·=· end`
   - `X ·> then`
   - `X ·> when`
   - `X ·> end`

   `X` in the above relations refers to any binary or unary operator, any value terminal, `(` and `)`.

   It's straightforward to find left- and right-precedence functions for all of those terminals; the pattern will be similar to that of parentheses in a standard algebraic grammar.

Comment: This is not really an accurate answer to the question. The question is about control flow statements and expressions, as per the title, and there is a case statement in the question. You can't parse those with an operator precedence parser.

Comment: @EJP: you absolutely can. It is clearly an operator grammar, since no production has two consecutive non-terminals, and the precedence relations are easy to deduce. I'll put them in my answer if you think that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

The Shunting-yard algorithm is for expressions with unary and binary operators. You need something more powerful such as LL(1) or LALR(1) to parse control flow statements, and once you have that it will also handle expressions as well. No need for the Shunting-yard algorithm at all.

Comment: This is not really an accurate answer to the question, although I agree that OP should be using LALR(1). But ternary operators and `(cond...)`-type constructions, (which is what OP is really asking about) are certainly amenable to operator-precedence parsing.

Comment: @rici This is not really an accurate comment on my answer. I haven't said you can't parse ternary operators with an operator precedence parser. The question is about control flow statements and expressions, and there is a case statement in the question. You can't parse those with an operator precedence parser.